# ROS Answers SE migration: publish a path

Tags: ros, path, ros-indigo, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to publish a path, but with this code I can publish only one point at a time:
geometry_msgs::Point msg;

What can I do to publish the path?
This page should work, but I don't know exactly how to write the code for it.
http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html

Can you help me out?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282094/publish-a-path/) by [Chris_ROSuser](https://answers.ros.org/users/32963/chris_rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To fill that kind of messages, create a `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped` and then insert it in the vector poses in the `nav_msgs/Path` message.

Note that in C++, an variable length array is a `std::vector`.

So it should look like:

```
nav_msgs::Path path;

geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose;

pose.header.stamp = ...;
pose.header.frame_id = ...;
pose.pose.position.x = ...;
[...]

path.header.stamp = ...;
path.header.frame_id = ...;
path.poses.push_back(pose);
```

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-16**:
once you publish a path, how do you make a robot follow the published path in rviz?
I am using this [package](http://github.com/open-rdc/fulanghua_navigation) to publish predefined paths
but my robot wont move along the path...

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2018-06-25**:
@aarontan It is a complex subject.
Maybe you can start here: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation